# Have vs. Will have vs. Will be having

Tags: tense, difference, phrase-usage

What differences are there between using the present tense 'have', future tense 'will have', and the future progressive tense 'will be having' in the following two sentences (one statement and one question):

1) I HAVE/ WILL HAVE / WILL BE HAVING a test tomorrow morning.

My thoughts: 'Will have' seems to be the least likely option as it indicates a sudden decision of wanting to take a test as opposed to sitting a scheduled event planned in advance. 'Have' is definitely more common than 'will be having', yet I don't see any problems with the latter. So why is that the case???

2) Does anyone know when we WILL BE HAVING / WILL HAVE/ HAVE the test?

My thoughts: My ear tells me using 'have' here is grammatically incorrect, as the sentence calls for the usage of future tense in that position. What I find hard to distinguish however are the other two. When should I choose 'will be having' over 'will have' and vice versa???

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the simple present to state facts which are true or regular occurrences.

- "I **have** a test tomorrow."  (It is a truth)
- "I **have** tests on Mondays." (a regular occurrence)

Use the simple future to state a prediction, as a future imperative or to state a promise.

- "I haven't done the homework so **I will have** a test tomorrow for sure."
- "You **will have** broccoli."  (you have no choice)
- "I **will have** homework." (you can rely on it)

Use the future progressive to describe a simultaneous event (especially as a prediction) or a simultaneous event that occurs regularly.

- "I **will be having** a test when they set off the fire alarm."
- "I **will be having** a test and I will completely forget everything."

Answer (score 4):

"To have" events such as classes, meetings, and tests, is a common expression and completely correct.

*I will have a test tomorrow morning* is definitive. You will definitely have a test the following morning.

*I will be having a test tomorrow morning* is continuous: in the future, the event will happen for an uncertain duration.

If the duration is known, for instance, the simple future is the most logical:

> I will have a three hour meeting on Tuesday morning.

Comment: Why would the duration of the test have any bearing upon the choice of tense?  Why is *I have a three-hour meeting on Tuesday morning* any less "logical" than *I will have a three-hour meeting on Tuesday morning*? Even the continuous seems no less logical than the simple future.  You could be explaining your exam schedule to someone.

Comment: *For anyone interested, we will be having a two-hour review session tomorrow afternoon.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It is illogical to use a continuous tense to express something that will take place for a certain duration. As Grammarly states [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/future-continuous-tense/), the simple future is used "when an action is expected to occur in the future and be completed."

Comment: You're putting too much stock in Grammarly.  There's nothing "illogical" about it.   The continuous expresses duration. Known durations are not excluded.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'm tired of having to justify the use of sources to other people (like I've been doing for the past week), but I will say this; using any of the three tenses is not _incorrect_. I didn't say that nor did I mean that. What I'm saying is that the simple future expresses a beginning and an end to something in the future. A continuous tense is, as the name suggests, _continuous_, but the action of meeting is not continuous in my case, especially given a specified duration.

Comment: "The future continuous tense, sometimes also referred to as the future progressive tense, is a verb tense that indicates that something will occur in the future and continue for an expected length of time."

Comment: That's what Grammarly says.  But the part about "expected length of time" is not a requirement.  It should say "and continue for some time".  *We will be thrashing out these details tomorrow. It might take 10 minutes. It could take all day. Who knows?*

Comment: You're confusing continuous with recurrent when you write "but the action of meeting is not continuous in my case, especially given a specified duration"  That the duration is known does not make it less a duration.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo _Continuous_ means _without stopping_. A two-hour meeting will not be _continuous_: it will stop after two hours. If you say to someone that you'll have a **three-hour** meeting, you don't expect the response to be "Well, how long do you think it'll be?"

Comment: "continuous" does not mean *perpetual*. A continuous action is one that takes place *over a period of time*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63572/discussion-between-kman3-and-tomauo).