# "At this time tomorrow we <will have> <will be having> a class." Which is the way to put it?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"At this time tomorrow we will have / will be having a class."

If both are possible, what's the difference in meaning?

Comment: It depends whether you are referring to the time the class starts, or thinking about where you will be at a certain time tomorrow.

Comment: So, "...will have a class" = "...will start a class" whereas "...will be having" = "will be in the middle of the process called a class", right?

Comment: That's how I would understand it.

Comment: Are you interested in the fact or the action?

Answer (score 0):

“At this time tomorrow we will have class.” This sentence is stating a future absolute fact and sounds like you are creating a schedule or reiterating an existing schedule.
“At this time tomorrow we will be having class.” This sentence sounds more informal and also gives the impression that class will have already started at this time tomorrow.

You might also look back at this discussion [Have vs. Will have vs. Will be having](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137673/have-vs-will-have-vs-will-be-having)